# jQuery Resizable detect elements underneath?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable, gridpak

I'm using a 48 column grid generated by GridPak to render out 48 1 "span" columns to illustrate 15 minute chunks of time in a 12 hour period.

I want to be able to drag a 15 minute chunk to increase the time duration. I'm using jQueryUI resizeable to handle the resize. The problem is I need to detect the number of columns I pass over when I resize the column. That way when the `stop` event fires I can determine how many columns I need to span and remove them from the list to prevent it from overflowing.

In the snippet below, i'm using `elementFromPoint()` to determine which element corresponds to the elements position but it just returns the jQueryUI helper element because it is the top most element.

Is there a better way to return the elements that sit underneath the resized column?

```js
$(".col").resizable({
  helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
  maxHeight: 20,
  minHeight: 20,
  grid: 40,
  handles: 'e',
  resize: function(event, ui) {

    console.log($(document.elementFromPoint(ui.position.left + ui.size.width, ui.position.top)));

    console.log(ui.position.left + ui.size.width);

  }
});
```

```css
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    .col {
      background: #333;
      height: 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
    .ui-resizable-helper {
      outline: 1px dotted #0f0;
    }







    /*!
 * Gridpak Beta CSS
 *
 * Generator - http://gridpak.com/
 * Created by @erskinedesign
 */
    /* Reusable column setup */
    .col {
      border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      float: left;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-background-clip: padding-box !important;
      -webkit-background-clip: padding-box !important;
      background-clip: padding-box !important;
    }
    /* 1. 48 Column Grid 0px - Infinity 
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    
    Span 1:    2.08333333333%
    Span 2:    4.16666666667%
    Span 3:    6.25%
    Span 4:    8.33333333333%
    Span 5:    10.4166666667%
    Span 6:    12.5%
    Span 7:    14.5833333333%
    Span 8:    16.6666666667%
    Span 9:    18.75%
    Span 10:    20.8333333333%
    Span 11:    22.9166666667%
    Span 12:    25.0%
    Span 13:    27.0833333333%
    Span 14:    29.1666666667%
    Span 15:    31.25%
    Span 16:    33.3333333333%
    Span 17:    35.4166666667%
    Span 18:    37.5%
    Span 19:    39.5833333333%
    Span 20:    41.6666666667%
    Span 21:    43.75%
    Span 22:    45.8333333333%
    Span 23:    47.9166666667%
    Span 24:    50.0%
    Span 25:    52.0833333333%
    Span 26:    54.1666666667%
    Span 27:    56.25%
    Span 28:    58.3333333333%
    Span 29:    60.4166666667%
    Span 30:    62.5%
    Span 31:    64.5833333333%
    Span 32:    66.6666666667%
    Span 33:    68.75%
    Span 34:    70.8333333333%
    Span 35:    72.9166666667%
    Span 36:    75.0%
    Span 37:    77.0833333333%
    Span 38:    79.1666666667%
    Span 39:    81.25%
    Span 40:    83.3333333333%
    Span 41:    85.4166666667%
    Span 42:    87.5%
    Span 43:    89.5833333333%
    Span 44:    91.6666666667%
    Span 45:    93.75%
    Span 46:    95.8333333333%
    Span 47:    97.9166666667%
    Span 48:    100%
    
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    @media screen and (min-width: 0px) {
      .row {
        margin-left: -1px;
      }
      .col {
        border-left-width: 1px;
        padding: 0 0%;
      }
      /*
        Add your semantic classnames in alongside their corresponding spans here. e.g.
        
        .span_3,
        .my_semantic_class_name {
            ...
        }
        */
      .span_1 {
        width: 2.08333333333%;
      }
      .span_2 {
        width: 4.16666666667%;
      }
      .span_3 {
        width: 6.25%;
      }
      .span_4 {
        width: 8.33333333333%;
      }
      .span_5 {
        width: 10.4166666667%;
      }
      .span_6 {
        width: 12.5%;
      }
      .span_7 {
        width: 14.5833333333%;
      }
      .span_8 {
        width: 16.6666666667%;
      }
      .span_9 {
        width: 18.75%;
      }
      .span_10 {
        width: 20.8333333333%;
      }
      .span_11 {
        width: 22.9166666667%;
      }
      .span_12 {
        width: 25.0%;
      }
      .span_13 {
        width: 27.0833333333%;
      }
      .span_14 {
        width: 29.1666666667%;
      }
      .span_15 {
        width: 31.25%;
      }
      .span_16 {
        width: 33.3333333333%;
      }
      .span_17 {
        width: 35.4166666667%;
      }
      .span_18 {
        width: 37.5%;
      }
      .span_19 {
        width: 39.5833333333%;
      }
      .span_20 {
        width: 41.6666666667%;
      }
      .span_21 {
        width: 43.75%;
      }
      .span_22 {
        width: 45.8333333333%;
      }
      .span_23 {
        width: 47.9166666667%;
      }
      .span_24 {
        width: 50.0%;
      }
      .span_25 {
        width: 52.0833333333%;
      }
      .span_26 {
        width: 54.1666666667%;
      }
      .span_27 {
        width: 56.25%;
      }
      .span_28 {
        width: 58.3333333333%;
      }
      .span_29 {
        width: 60.4166666667%;
      }
      .span_30 {
        width: 62.5%;
      }
      .span_31 {
        width: 64.5833333333%;
      }
      .span_32 {
        width: 66.6666666667%;
      }
      .span_33 {
        width: 68.75%;
      }
      .span_34 {
        width: 70.8333333333%;
      }
      .span_35 {
        width: 72.9166666667%;
      }
      .span_36 {
        width: 75.0%;
      }
      .span_37 {
        width: 77.0833333333%;
      }
      .span_38 {
        width: 79.1666666667%;
      }
      .span_39 {
        width: 81.25%;
      }
      .span_40 {
        width: 83.3333333333%;
      }
      .span_41 {
        width: 85.4166666667%;
      }
      .span_42 {
        width: 87.5%;
      }
      .span_43 {
        width: 89.5833333333%;
      }
      .span_44 {
        width: 91.6666666667%;
      }
      .span_45 {
        width: 93.75%;
      }
      .span_46 {
        width: 95.8333333333%;
      }
      .span_47 {
        width: 97.9166666667%;
      }
      .span_48 {
        margin-left: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="page">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="header col span_1">1</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">2</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">3</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">4</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">5</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">6</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">7</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">8</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">9</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">10</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">11</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">12</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">13</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">14</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">15</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">16</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">17</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">18</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">19</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">20</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">21</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">22</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">23</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">24</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">25</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">26</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">27</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">28</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">29</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">30</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">31</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">32</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">33</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">34</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">35</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">36</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">37</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">38</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">39</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">40</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">41</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">42</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">43</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">44</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">45</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">46</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">47</div>
    <div class="header col span_1">48</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```